# Google apps script search spreadsheet

Tags: google-apps-script

In "A simple search tool UI" ([Instant search using TextBox and onKeyUp and onKeyDown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11628743/instant-search-using-textbox-and-onkeyup-and-onkeydown)) you can list all the records found (and not one at a time) in the panel?
how can I do?
thanks

Answer (score 0):

the code you are asking for is a bit more complex... [here is an example](https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbxquizfGo85vdeaN7_qss2-LY--UxSLFFeF5ML5rXPWZfrX9oNt/exec) of such a search tool, the source is available [here](https://script.google.com/d/1aL_y6ZqrfqrzhDZ4yzxM9Ax5hGi9KOHR0ltZ-7gVOTpQCDXV9zY3Ka_Y/edit) but I hope you're familiar with GAS ;-)